# SQL: Last Occurrence of a format

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr

I have a (oracle) text field as below. It is a summary logging information of a ticket which includes the related user code, date and time followed by some comments. As you can see I have dates in this field, but as a string.
I would like to pull out the last occurrence of the date format, in this case '2015-09-07'. Or even better if I can pull out the date when comment is 'Ticket Fixed' or 'Ticket Closed'.

```
{ABC, 2015-08-31 10:27}: Ticket Issued 151553
{ANN, 2015-09-07 13:34}: Assigned to user 'FAR'
{MJJ, 2015-09-07 13:37}: Comments added
{MFR, 2015-09-07 13:37}: Ticket fixed
```

I tried to use SUBSTR but that will not work because the content/length of the last comment might change.

Using Oracle Database.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ddc2/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets( details ) AS 
SELECT '{ABC, 2015-08-31 10:27}: Ticket Issued 151553' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{ANN, 2015-09-07 13:34}: Assigned to user ''FAR''' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{MJJ, 2015-09-07 13:37}: Comments added' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{MFR, 2015-09-07 13:37}: Ticket fixed' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT SUBSTR( details, 2,3 ) AS id,
         TO_DATE( SUBSTR( details, 7,16 ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' ) AS time,
         SUBSTR( details, 26 ) AS ticket_comment
  FROM   tickets
)
WHERE  ticket_comment IN ( 'Ticket fixed', 'Ticket Closed' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ddc2/4/0)**:

```
|  ID |                 TIME | TICKET_COMMENT |
|-----|----------------------|----------------|
| MFR | 2015-09-07T13:37:00Z |   Ticket fixed |
```